# How to hide my IMEI number from remote requests

Tags: settings, remote-control, imei

I have an Asus ZenFone 5, with Android 9. I wouls like to hide IMEI number from remote requests to know the number, and hide remote requests to know if a phone Cell is using Developer Mode activated. Or If have any software or configuraration that block any remote request to verify any phone configuration.

Thank you.

Comment: What remote requests are you talking about? When and how an IMEI is used is defined in the GSM standard.

Comment: Uber, I don't know how, is blocking driver's phones to log on app, based on IMEI code, If driver had activated developer mode on your phone.

Comment: Uber after August update has made housing rooting impossible by any known means AFAIK. Even for end users//There is an Edxposed module by IAmNotADeveloper on Github that hides the status of developer mode just as FYI

Comment: See this Post in thread ' [MODULE] Play Integrity Fix' https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-play-integrity-fix.4607985/post-88888957

Comment: It's always best to give your device details, Android version, the app with which you are having a problem, whether the device is rooted, Edxposed installed and if so what modules etc, instead of getting into a guessing game. It helps others to suggest a solution or else readers tend to skip